# Jenkins pipeline: join file / URL paths

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I join strings nicely into a path when programming Jenkins Groovy pipeline? So that I can `join('http://example.com/', '/r', 'some.html') -> 'http://example.com/r/some.html'`

[This note](https://serviceorientedarchitect.com/how-to-combinejoin-file-paths-in-gradlegroovy/) suggests using `new File(dir1, dir2)` or `Paths.get(dir1, dir2)` in "pure" Groovy.

However in Jenkins pipeline, `import java.nio.file.Paths` gives me

```
No such static method found: staticMethod java.nio.file.Paths get java.lang.String org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl.
```

and with `new File` I get

```
Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

and I kinda agree with Jenkins on this do not want to allow this. Is there another way?

Comment: how about joining them as strings and then creating a file object?
def stringPath = ['http://example.com/', '/r', 'some.html'].join('/')

Answer (score 3):

bad idea to build url with Paths or File objects because under windows you'll get wrong result.

you can build url with simple string concatenation and use `URI.normalize()` to remove extra slashes:

```
def u = new URI(['http://example.com/', '/r', 'some.html'].join('/')).normalize().toString()
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, causes `Scripts not permitted to use new java.net.URI java.lang.String` too, but thank you kindly on heads-up about Paths and Windows backslashes!

Comment: `Scripts not permitted ... Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.` actually tells you what to do - ask admin to approve this code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 def join_two_urls(url1, url2) {
    if (url1 == "" || url2 == "") {
        println "Error: must provde two invalid urls."
        return ""
    }
    println "Joining ${url1} and ${url2} ..."
    if (url1 ==~ /.*\/$/) {
        url1 = url1.substring(0, url1.length() - 1)
    }
    if (url2 ==~ /^\/.*/) {
        url2 = url2.substring(1, url2.length())
    }
    return url1 + "/" + url2
}

def join_paths(String[] urls) {
    if (urls.size() <= 1) {
        println "Error: invalid urls."
        return ""
    }
    conbined_url = ""
    pre_url = ""
    for (url in urls) {
        if (pre_url == "") {
            pre_url = url
            continue
        }
        conbined_url += join_two_urls(pre_url, url)
    }
    return conbined_url
}

println join_paths("xx/", "xxx/" , "/fsdsdfsdf")
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but that's exactly what I was trying to avoid: self-written logic and substring juggling for something that is highly hidden somewhere in standard library.