# Jenkins : PowerShell script not found

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Groovy script run by Jenkins, and this script contains the instruction :

```
Boolean myValue = powershell(script: "./myScript.ps1", returnStatus: true)
```

When the Groovy script is run, I get the following error :

```
powershell.exe : ./myScript.ps1 : The term './myScript.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a 
            At C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProject@tmp\durable-f15db675\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
            + & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
            + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (./myScript.ps1... the name of a :String) [], RemoteException
                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
             
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.

At C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProject@tmp\durable-f15db675\powershellScript.ps1:1 char:1
+ ./myScript.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./myScript.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and `myValue` is then `True`.

The Groovy and PowerShell scripts are both in the same directory (at least on the Git repository where Jenkins gets the Groovy script).

In the Groovy script, there are other PowerShell calls, but with direct commands, not ps1 script files. And they're OK.

1. Where does Jenkins is supposed to put these scripts ? I can't find them in the workspace.
2. Could the problem be caused by rights on the PowerShell script ?
3. Why does the Groovy script not fail ? Why does it continue ?
4. Why does `myValue == true` ? Is it because the `returnStatus` argument ?

**EDIT 1** : The path given for the script is wrong. The "." directory points to the workspace, not the directory where the Groovy script is located. I have now to find a way to get this path...

**EDIT 2** : EDIT 1 was wrong !! See my answer below.

Comment: You'll want to explicitly set the working directory of the process to the location where the script file exists. Can you share definition or documentation for the `powershell(...)` function?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-windows-powershell-script

Comment: If you can't specify the working directory: pass the fully rooted path to the script, eg: `powershell(script: /C:\path\to\script.ps1/, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that neither Groovy code in the pipeline nor PowerShell code you invoke via the [`powershell` plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/) are stored in script *files on disk*.

*Invisible, transient helper script files* may be used *behind the scenes*, as evidenced by the `.ps1` script path in your error message.

The error message also implies that the *working directory* is a *temporary* one whose path is auto-generated.

A `powershell` step's [`script:` parameter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-windows-powershell-script) actually expects an *inline* script, i.e. directly accepts PowerShell *source code* rather than the path of an external `.ps1` file.

---

To answer your questions, building on the above:

> Where does Jenkins is supposed to put these scripts ? I can't find them in the workspace.

It follows from the above that trying to invoke a `.ps1` script *file* won't work via `./`, i.e. by referring to the - unknown-to-you - working directory, given that you won't know ahead of time where to place the file.

If you cannot use *inline* PowerShell code, as described above, you must place your `myScript.ps1` file in a persistent location that you must reference by its *full path*, ideally expressed via an environment variable, e.g. the `env.WORKSPACE` variable provided by Jenkins; something like
`powershell(script: (env.WORKSPACE + './myScript.ps1'), returnStatus: true)`

> Could the problem be caused by rights on the PowerShell script ?

No, the error message implies simply that the file could not be found in the working directory

> Why does the Groovy script not fail ? Why does it continue ?

`returnStatus: true` deactivates the default fail-on-nonzero-process-exit-code logic; see next point.

> Why does myValue == true ? Is it because the `returnStatus` argument ?

Yes, but `myValue` should be `1` in your case, i.e. it should report the process exit code of the PowerShell CLI.

---

###### Original answer: Only applies to running Groovy code from a *script file*:

If the PowerShell script is located in the same directory as your Groovy script, you must invoke it via the *latter*'s directory path, not the *current* one (`.`):

```
// Get the full path of the 'myScript.ps1' script located in the same
// dir. as the executing Groovy script.
powerShellScriptFilePath = 
  getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path +
  '/../myScript.ps1'

Boolean myValue = powershell(script: powerShellScriptFilePath, returnStatus: true)
```

Note:

- The technique for determining the running Groovy script file's own file path was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169196/45375).
- The above technique works in stand-alone Groovy scripts - I cannot personally verify if it works from Jenkins.
- It uses `..` to reach the *directory* path from the script's own file path, which PowerShell is capable of resolving (also note that PowerShell recognizes `\` and `/` as path separators interchangeably, even on Windows). This is not only a simple solution, but avoids the use of `new File()`, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53915130/45375) suggests  may not be permitted *from Jenkins* - see code below.
- [This companion answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475957/45375) shows an alternative via the [`@SourceUri`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/SourceURI.html) annotation, which, however, may also not be usable from Jenkins - do tell us if you have more information.

More proper way to construct the full companion file path (may not work in Jenkins):

```
// Get the full path of the 'myScript.ps1' script located in the same
// dir. as the executing Groovy script.
powerShellScriptFilePath = 
  new File(
    new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent, 
    'myScript.ps1'
  )

Boolean myValue = powershell(script: powerShellScriptFilePath, returnStatus: true)
```

Comment: Actually, for some executions of the jenkins job, the Groovy and PowerScript scripts are in the working directory. I guess the Groovy files are initially loaded in RAM, and later copied in the working directory.

Comment: @Oodini, please see my update (new top section).

Comment: Thank you for this very complete anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I've understood the problem.

I am maintaining some IC code, and I am also discovering scripting in Jenkins... :)

Here is what's happening :

At the beginning, all the scripts (Groovy and PowerShell) are retrieved in the workspace from a Git repository. Then, all the Groovy scripts are loaded (so put in RAM).

Later, under some conditions, the workspace is totally cleaned (call of `deleteDir()`). It is done purposely, to get a fresh C++ build.
The Groovy files are still in RAM, but the PowerShell scripts are not accessible anymore. So, later, when I want to call them, they're not found.

As the Groovyu script running was OK, and they were not in the workspace, I thought they were stored anywhere, in a secret land (I repeat : I am discovering Jenkins scripting and some scripts already developed). So I was troubled.

Everything is clear now.

Thanks @mklement0 for having completed my understanding.